# If there is/are any

Tags: grammar

Are both of the following sentences correct?

> If there are (any) cars parked in the road, they will be towed away.
>
> If there is any car parked in the road, it will be towed away.

I know we generally use the first sentence in these circumstances. But is there any situation where I can use the second sentence? I have seen people use the second sentence too but not so often.

One more question, if I omit 'any' in the first sentence (If there are cars parked in the road, they will be towed away), will that be correct too?

Comment: Both are acceptable and why is this not a Question for *English Language Learners*, please?

Comment: Sentence 2 sounds really awkward to me. I would definitely not use it. I would prefer sentence 1. Or, "If a car is parked in the road, it will be towed away."

Comment: They're both correct, but "Cars parked in the road will be towed away" says the same thing more efficiently.

Comment: strictly, the first allows the possibility that a single car would not be towed away.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can use the second sentence in any situation in which the first one is used.  There is no real difference in correctness or meaning, as far as I can tell.  It seems to simply be a matter of learned patterns that causes the first one to be more popular.

Also, the first sentence should be just as correct without the use of the word any.

Comment: Equally, you could omit the 'if' part. "Any car(s) left parked in the road will be towed away".